# React-slick: Adding animation while sliding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I had created a slider using react slick now there is a requirement to change transition and animation of slides on prev and next button click. Got some help that add class to currently active slide while changing slide and add animation and transition effect to it. And remove after it slides completely changed. I tried but it is not working as expecting.
First it is not adding classe on next or prev button button click
Second it is adding class on swiping slide but it disturbs other carousel items
Here is my code

```
  const settings = {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    infinite: false,
    beforeChange,
    afterChange,
    useCSS: false,
    useTransform : false
  }

  const beforeChange = (prev: number, next: number) => {
    let element = document.querySelector('.slick-active');
    element?.classList.add('next-slide-anim');
    setIndex(next);
  };

  const afterChange = (index : number) => {
    let element = document.querySelector('.slick-active');
    element.classList.remove('next-slide-anim')
  };

  const settings = {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    infinite: false,
    beforeChange,
    afterChange,
    useCSS: false,
    useTransform : false
  }

  const next = () => {
    sliderRef.current.slickNext()
  };

  const previous = () => {
    sliderRef.current.slickPrev();
  };

 <div className="home-slider">
            <div className="carousel">
              <Slider {...settings} className="carousel-inner" ref={ref => sliderRef.current = ref}>
                {
                  slides.map((slide: any, index) => (
                    <div className="carousel-item" key={index} ref={ref => carouselRef.current = ref}>
                      <div className="slide-content">
                        {index !== slides.length - 1 &&
                          <>
                            <h3>{slide.username}</h3>
                            <span id="user-icon-link">
                              <Link to="/" target="_blank">
                                <img src="/images/homeScreen/instagram.png" alt="link-icon" width="20" height="20" />{slide.userlink}</Link>
                            </span>
                          </>
                        }
                      </div>
                      <img src={slide.path} alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500" />
                    </div>
                  ))
                }
              </Slider>
              {((slides.length !== 0) && (index !== slides.length - 1)) &&
                <>
                  {(index !== 0) && <a href="#/" className="carousel-control-prev" onClick={previous}>
                    <img src="/images/homeScreen/skipnewbtn.png" alt="Los Angeles" />
                  </a>}
                  {index !== slides.length - 1 && <a href="#/" className="carousel-control-next" id="next-btn" onClick={next}  >
                    <img src="/images/homeScreen/fast-forward-button.gif" alt="Los Angeles" />
                  </a>}
                </>
              }
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.slick-active`, you can get the slide elements in your `beforeChange` by using the index values passed to the function and then add/remove the classes from the appropriate slides. Without seeing your CSS, I'm guessing that you want to add your animation in the `beforeChange`, but if it works out better, you could always move the `classList.add()` to your `afterChange`.

```js
const beforeChange = (prev: number, next: number) => {
  const prevSlideElement = slider.current.innerSlider.list.querySelector(`[data-index="${prev}"]`);
  const nextSlideElement = slider.current.innerSlider.list.querySelector(`[data-index="${next}"]`);

  prevSlideElement.classList.remove('next-slide-anim');
  nextSlideElement.classList.add('next-slide-anim');
}
```

Comment: Here is my css its just simple tansform and tansition
.next-slide-anim{
transform: rotate(-30deg) !important;
    transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
}
And want to add animation class to the slide which is sliding

Comment: Did you try my solution above? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Response of Ed is good, but need one more trick !

`beforeChange` is triggerd before react-slick add his internal classes like "current-slide", so  `next-slide-anim` is override and animation don't show up...

To correct this we need to call a `Timeout` function to trigger code on next tick.

```js
const beforeChange = (prev: number, next: number) => {
  const prevSlideElement = slider.current.innerSlider.list.querySelector(`[data-index="${prev}"]`);
  const nextSlideElement = slider.current.innerSlider.list.querySelector(`[data-index="${next}"]`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    prevSlideElement.classList.remove('next-slide-anim');
    nextSlideElement.classList.add('next-slide-anim');
  });
}
```